# Jquery reload div content on select change using php ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

OK here is my code

portfolio.php

```
            <select name="portfolio" id="portfolio_dropdown" class="service-dropdown">
                <?php foreach($years as $year){ ?>
                   <option value="<?php echo $year['year']; ?>"><?php echo $year['year']; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        <div class="loading"></div>
        <div id="portfolio">
            <div id="port-cont">
               <?php foreach($portfolios as $portfolio){ ?>
               <div class="video">
                <div class="play">
                    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/v/<?php echo $portfolio['url']; ?>">Play</a>
                </div>
              <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/v/<?php echo $portfolio['url']; ?>"frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    <h3><?php echo $portfolio['title']; ?></h3>
                    <p><?php echo $portfolio['text']; ?></p>
               </div>
               <?php } ?>
        </div>
        </div>
```

my js code

```
$("body").on('change','#portfolio_dropdown',function(){
     var year = $(this).val();

     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "catalog/controller/portfolio.php",
       data: "year="+year,
       beforeSend: function(){
         $(".loading").show();
         $("#portfolio").empty();
       },
       success: function(portfolio_data){
         $(".loading").hide();
          $("#portfolio").html(portfolio_data);
       }
     });
});
```

my portfolio controller file

```
if(isset($_POST['year'])){
  include_once "../../system/validation.php";
  include_once "../model/DataBase.php";
  include_once "../model/Display.php";

  $year = integer($_POST['year']);

  $get_portfolio_data = new Display("portfolio");

  $portfolios = $get_portfolio_data->getDataByColumnName("year",$year);

 include_once "../view/themes/default/template/portfolio_data.php";

  exit();
}
```

My portfolio file "the first one " i get my data with another function that i get my last year(2014) portfolio data

so when i change the year i call my controller file to get the data related to that year

my question here is how to return $portfolios that i got from my controller file so i don't have to change my template file code or include another file as i did

i mean i need to reload my portfolio.php template content

i tried something like this

```
$("body").on('change','#portfolio_dropdown',function(){
     var year = $(this).val();

     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "catalog/controller/portfolio.php",
       data: "year="+year,
       beforeSend: function(){
         $(".loading").show();
         $("#portfolio").hide();
       },
       success: function(portfolio_data){
         $(".loading").hide();
          $("#portfolio").show().load("portfolio" + " #port-cont");
       }
     });
});
```

but i don't know how to send my new $portfolios data to the same div without including another template file

Actually i'm little confused how to do this properly

So i hope you got what i want to do :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate `portfolio-div.php` file that only contains the code you want to replace with, and call that from the `$.ajax` call.

Or you can add a `$_GET` parameter like `?skiptemplate=1` to `portfolio.php` so that when you call the file with that parameter, the surrounding template markup is skipped when the file is called from an ajax call.

If you do not have the opportunity to change the server-side code, you can load the whole template file again, but extract only the `#port-cont` part to replace the existing content. Don't use `load()` (which itself will call an URL), use `html()` instead:

```
$("#portfolio").show().html(portfolio_data);
```

(though this will insert all HTML, not only the `#port-cont` part)

Comment: I already did that portfolio-div.php as it is included in my controller file , but the problem with that i can't use my jquery code on the loaded data , my portfolio_data.php file is the same code as in my #portfolio div but i can't use my jquery functions on my new loaded data

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#portfolio").html(portfolio_data)
```

Just pass the parameter into html

Comment: There is a problem here is when i include my new template file from my controller file , i can't use my jquery functions on this new data